# Controlling GPIO's of ESP8266 (NodeMCU) using KAA Sandbox (0.10.0)

Tags: nodemcu, kaa

The tutorial is given for older version of KAA Sandbox. Can some please explain how to do the same in newest version (0.10.0).
    Particularly, which demo application should I fuse node-mcu with.

Answer (score 0):

The ESP8266 sample application was not ready at the time of Kaa 0.10 Sandbox release. Thus, it was disabled on the Sandbox.

The new version is available in the Kaa Sample Applications GitHub 
[repository](https://github.com/kaaproject/sample-apps/tree/master/gpiocontrol). You should use the Kaa SDK from the Kaa 0.10 Sandbox, but the code from the **master** branch.

It was planned to release Kaa 0.10.1 Sandbox where the application is again enabled, but the date of the release is not defined yet.